# Why is the border-left border-right not working for Bootstrap 5 Django?

Tags: django, border, bootstrap-5

So I have the following code:

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Verification Code Email</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .insta-icon{width:50%; float:right;}
    </style>    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1 offset-1 border-right">    # This one right here
                <img class="insta-icon"src="{% static '/images/instagram_icon.png' %}">                 
            </div>
            <div class="col-10"> b</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now when I do just `border`, the border is shown, and when I do `border-bottom` or `border-top`, the borders are shown. However, when I use `border-left` or `border-right`, the border outlines aren't shown.

Also, I tried using a styles by adding an `insta-nav` class to the div class and override the styles by adding `border:1px`, but the border isn't added.

Why would the reasons for these two be so?? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `border-start` or `border-end` instead of `border-left` or `border-right` in bootstrap 5.

Horizontal direction sensitive variables, utilities and mixins are renamed with more logical names — `start` and `end` in lieu of `left` and `right` in **Bootstrap 5**.

You can see more bootstrap 5 migration details here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#sass

Comment: That really annoying in my opinion. They could have just let it in or add the possibility to enable the old-style with a mixin or something. When I want a margin-right "mr" just makes sense - even if you don't know bootstrap you will understand it easily and translate it in your head almost immediately. LTR support is neat - if you need it - which i don't. Leaves a bad taste to have a layer of abstraction for a feature i might not need- ever. Will give it a shot but 99% sure i'll end up with declaring all "old" margin/padding variations in my own css :/